# Remove figcation from excerpt

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

I am trying to customize my frontpage and currently i'm confused why i can't get rid of the figcation in the excerpt.

As far as i know `the_excerpt()`should already remove tags and shortcodes. Just in case i tried `strip_shortcodes( the_excerpt() );` to get rid of the figcaption. Doesn't work.

It's just a regular image with a caption.

Answer (score 0):

Use directly in the templates.

```
echo strip_shortcodes( get_the_excerpt() );
```

how does it work as follows ?

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'strip_shortcodes');
```

or

```
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'strip_shortcodes');
```